# where to find presto latest version repository and presto release notes

Tags: presto, trino

Sorry if I ask details about the right place for download presto version , but for now we are using presto version - `presto-server-317`

we want to move to the highest presto version - `presto-server-350`

we saw that the please for the new presto version is on mvnrepository repository on link - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prestosql/presto-server/350/

but we not sure if this is the official place !

but I could not find the documentation about this new version , and prerequisites before implantation the presto `version - 350`

I will appreciate to get help about where are the documentation for `presto version 350` , and how to know the release notes for `presto version 350`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the PrestoSQL project [was renamed to Trino in December of 2020](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html).

[PrestoSQL version 350](https://trino.io/docs/350/overview.html) is the last version with the PrestoSQL brand. As of writing this answer, [Trino version 356](https://trino.io/docs/356/overview.html) is the latest version overall.

The latest release notes can always be found at https://trino.io/docs/current/release.html.

Due to the trademark that was [imposed by the Linux Foundation](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html), the namespace and therefore location of the presto artifacts were changed as well. You can find them here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/trino/trino-server/

You will likely want to migrate first to version 350 before migrating to the first Trino version (351). More information on this is [available in the migration guide](https://trino.io/blog/2021/01/04/migrating-from-prestosql-to-trino.html).